# how to change the hot-key used to invoke code insight?

Tags: delphi

I want to change the hot-key to invoke code insight in Delphi 2010, being the original `Ctrl` `enter`, i want to change it to `spacebar` without installing CnWizards, how can I archive this?

Comment: Ctrl+Enter has nothing to do with Code Insight (with the default keyboard layout, anyway). Code Completion is Ctrl+Space, Code Parameters is Ctrl+Shift+Space. Ctrl+Enter is used in the VB key bindings for Code Templates, and otherwise appears to only be used as a shortcut for the editor popup menu item "Open File At Cursor".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you could write an IDE wizard to do something like this, using a common key like space to trigger code insight would have many annoying side effects.  I can't recommend using such a common keystroke. Consider Ctrl+Space or Ctrl+Shift+Space.

Answer (score 2):

There is no built-in Delphi functionality to change that hotkey.

You can write your own IDE expert to do that. Since cnWizards already provides the functionality you want, the sources of cnWizard are a good start to see how to write your own IDE expert.

--jeroen